# Insert Func<T, int> value into linq-2-sql query

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, generics, c#-4.0

i have a multi-tenant application and all data is in the same database. We split the data for each tenant by a objectToTenant table.

In a generic Repository class i want to implement a method which filters the objects just by specifying which property of the object is the tenantToObjectRelationId and what type is the object (needed because different types are stored in the relation table)

The call i want to make should look like this:

```
// Specialized Repository class 
var allItemsForTenant =
    this.AllForTenant(item => item.RelationId, 123);
```

and therefore i've implemented this method:

```
// Generic Repository class
public virtual IQueryable<T> AllForTenant(
    Func<T, int> getObjectToTenantRelationId, string objectType)
{
    var result =
        from item in this.context.GetTable<T>( )
        join tenantObject in (
            from tenantRelationRecord in objectTenantRelationRepo.All( )
            where tenantRelationRecord.TenantId == Global.TenantId
            where tenantRelationRecord.ObjectTypeId == type.TypeId
            select tenantObjectRecord)
            on getObjectToTenantRelationId( item ) equals tenantObject.ObjectId
        select item;

    return result;
}
```

but at the moment i get a `NotSupportedException`

> Für die System.Object DynamicInvoke(System.Object[])-Methode gibt es
>   keine unterstützte Übersetzung in SQL.

which is caused by the `Func<T, int>` method which cannot be translated into sql.

How do i need to change the `Func<T, int>` so that it can be translated or does someone another solution?

Comment: Instead of passing in a `Func<T, int>` pass in an `IQueryable` with all the possible items and use that to join.

Comment: For Entity Framework to be able to translate it, you have to pass in an `Expression<Func<T, int>>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simplest fix would be to pass `Expression<Func<T,int>>` instead of just `Func<T,int>`. Passing an expression would allow the tree visitor to "step into" your expression rather than bounce off its name.

What's nice is that if you pass lambdas, the compiler will automatically create `Expression<Func<T,int>>` out of them, thus the only thing you have to change is the signature of your `AllForTenant` method.

Comment: If i change the signature to `Expression<Func<T,int>>` i get the error `'getObjectToTenantRelationId' is a 'variable' but is used like a method`

Comment: Using an `Expression` will only work when LINQ to SQL can translate this to SQL.

Comment: @Viper: although I have no idea how to apply `Expression<Func<T,int>>` using query-style syntax, however if you take a look at the extension method syntax then `.Join()` accepts expression. I've used this multiple times for filtering and it's the same situation - you have to switch to `.Where()` over `where`.

Comment: I don't know what exactly the difference is, but changing from query-style syntax to extension method syntay does the trick. `this.All( ).Join( tenantObjects, objectToTenantRelationsIds, item => item.ObjectId, (a, b) => a )`

Comment: @Viper: the difference is that the extension method syntax is more capable - it supports both `Func<>` and `Expression<Func<>>`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing in a `Func<T, int>` pass in a `IQueryable<Tuple<T, int>>` or something similar. This way LINQ to SQL knows how to translate it to SQL:

```
// Generic Repository class
public virtual IQueryable<T> AllForTenant(
    IQueryable<Tuple<T, int>> objectToTenentRelationIds, string objectType)
{
    var tenantObjects =
        from tenantRelationRecord in objectTenantRelationRepo.All()
        where tenantRelationRecord.TenantId == Global.TenantId
        where tenantRelationRecord.ObjectTypeId == type.TypeId
        select tenantObjectRecord;

    var result =
        from item in this.context.GetTable<T>()
        join objectToTenentRelationId in objectToTenentRelationIds
            on objectToTenentRelationId.Item1 equals item
        join tenantObject in tenantObjects
            on objectToTenentRelationIds.Item2 equals tenantObject.ObjectId
        select item;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: If i do what you suggest, then i need to select all objects before  calling the method of the generic base repository and pass them as parameter. That's the thing i try to avoid with my implementation.

Comment: Do don't have to get everything from the database. Don't forget that a `IQueryable` is just the definition of a query, not the data itself. LINQ to SQL will translate this to an efficient SQL query.

Comment: Sorry, maybe i didn't express myself clear. What i meant was that when i want to perform your query i need to make an additional linq-2-sql query in the specialized repository to be able to pass the `IQueryable` into the BaseRepository method. If i need to do this, then i can make the join to the objectTenantRelation directly in the specialized repository.

Comment: You can't use a .NET method inside a LINQ query, since LINQ to SQL can not translate it to SQL. You have to pass in something that can be translated. An `IQueryable` can. There are not many alternatives to this.